# Oracle 19c and "no valid ip address returned for the host"

Tags: oracle, networking, centos

I installed oracle 19c on centos 8, there was an error during installation when configuring the listener.
Manually running Net Assistance (/bin/netca) and trying to add a listener ends with a message: "no valid ip address returned for the host":

[image]

I performed an installation on Centos 7 with automatic preinstallation configuration under oracle and the same message.

I probably didn't configure something in linux, because I don't know much about it.

Comment: hi @tomasz , did you try to configure the listener manually ??

Comment: completely by hand? not by an assistant? No... No... let's not go that way.)

Answer (score 1):

After a week of hard work...

I managed to install, two possible reasons for this error:

1. I installed from my ORACLE account, but by "SU ORACLE" I did not log in as ORALCE, because then all the environment settings are loaded
2. I used another (newer) version of the oracle package for automatic configuration (https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/latest/x86_64/getPackage/oracle-database-preinstall-19c-1.0-2.el7.x86_64.rpm)
3. It's possible that I had a different hostname set in the oracle scripts than on the server in /etc/hostname - very likely, due to the content of the error...

Comment: Perhaps it was needed to edit the /etc/hosts and add the right ip or hostname.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was installing Oracle 19c in CentOS stream 8 in a VM with VirtualBox.

I added in `/etc/hosts: 10.0.2.15 centoss8 centoss8.local`
(before this I added CentOSs8 and CentOSs8.local as an alias of 127.0.0.1 and didn't work)

and in `/etc/hostname: centoss8.local`

reboot, and run
`/etc/init.d/oracledb_ORCLCDB-19c configure`

it's worked for me

Comment: I added nothing. I just runned the configure command line twice. It found the Host IP the second time. Go figure.

Comment: @KirKanos upvoted because that solved my problem as well. Sigh... Oracle...